# Using Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy, how could I change the database connection in a route?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Business case: 
We have multiple databases that need to be accessed and we don't know which until a URL/Route is called. The database server and database name are part of the route.

```
example: http://<flask_server>/<db_server>/<db_name>/weeklyreport
```

Since standard Flask-SQLAlchemy uses APP settings to define the DB connection and APP settings cannot (should not) be changed at runtime... how could one accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I've just sidestepped the issue by using straight SQLAlchemy and not Flask-SQLAlchemy as I could find no way around this. For my needs I won't miss the benefits of the Flask wrappers.